Back button browsing history with a javascript website just work once
I face a problem with my one page website and back navigation button of the browser,
when i load a new page i do this:


displayPage = function (page, json) {
        var stateObj = { "page": page, 'json': json };
        history.pushState(stateObj, "", page);
        // some code here



and after when the back button is trigerred :


$(function() {
    Skeleton._construct();
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        Skeleton.dispPage(event.state);
    }
});

this.dispPage = function(blob){
        displayPage(blob.page, blob.json);
}



but when i click on back button once, no problem onpopstat event is triggered, i go back and my previous page is loaded but if i click once more (or more) onpopstat is not triggered anymore...
what can i do?
many thanks by advance

I found the problem alone.
when I call the displayPage function I didn't check where the reloading came from and so I did a pushState each time and that broke the navigation history.
So I did this:


this.dispPage = function(blob){
        //i add a parameter here
        displayPage(blob.page, blob.json, 1);
}

displayPage = function (page, json, external = 0) {
        var stateObj = { "page": page, 'json': json };
        // i verify the parameter 'external' here
        if(external == 0){
          history.pushState(stateObj, "", page);
        }
        // some code here
}



I hope this can help someone
